# Table not updating using MERGE INTO

Tags: pyspark, delta-lake, databricks-sql

I have a dataframe which is converted to a Spark df in Azure Databricks, then a temporary view:

```
spark_df = spark.createDataFrame(df)
spark_df.createOrReplaceTempView("myTemp")
```

I use the following to insert columns to an existing table:

```
spark.sql(
    f"""MERGE INTO prp_b901_group_work.test_cg_policies_multiple_delta AS m
USING temp_table AS s
ON m.id = s.id
WHEN MATCHED THEN INSERT (m.premium_usd, m.limit_usd) VALUES (s.premium_usd, s.limit_usd)"""
)
```

So basically the intention is to use the columns that originated from the `spark_df` (`s.colnew_1, s.colnew_2`) into the table `x.y` (x - database; y - table). The two data sources match on the "id".

However, the error message is:

```
ParseException: 
[PARSE_SYNTAX_ERROR] Syntax error at or near 'INSERT'(line 4, pos 18)
```

Where is this going wrong?

Comment: You need to add more details.  Where is table x.y?  Is x the database and y the table.  Just do not know.  Try doing this with a sample databricks dataset (dbfs:/databricks-datasets/) so that everyone can follow along.  Also, I would not update the primary key when there is a match.  Most people update the other fields and/or date such as modified date.

Comment: @CRAFTYDBA: thank you for the that, I updated the original post with further descriptions.

Answer (score 0):

There is a coding issue here.  First, you do not need a F string.  Second, the INSERT statement takes column names, not references to the column.  I removed "m." from the column names.  Please try your code again.

```
stmt = """

  MERGE INTO 
      prp_b901_group_work.test_cg_policies_multiple_delta AS m
  USING 
      temp_table AS s 
  ON 
      m.id = s.id

  WHEN MATCHED THEN 
      INSERT (premium_usd, limit_usd) VALUES (s.premium_usd, s.limit_usd)

"""
```

Enclosed is the Databricks reference page for the MERGE statement.  Notice the indents I use for the statement.  It makes the reading the code easy.

https://docs.databricks.com/sql/language-manual/delta-merge-into.html